# IOS Swift- UIButton is not getting disabled within its own button click event

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am searching the location using filter method based on user input. User has to tab the button once the inout is given in the UITextfiled. 
Following is the button click event and I am not seeing the button not getting disabled after the same button is tapped.

```
@IBAction func searchGeoButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var matchedArray = ["No results"]
        var flag = false
         print("Button clicked")
         self.searchGeoLocationBut.isEnabled = false
          dropButton.hide()
        searchGeoTextField.shake()
         if let searchText =  searchGeoTextField.text, !searchText.isEmpty
        {
            matchedArray.removeAll()
            let unichar = "→"
            _ = locdata.filter { (location: Location) -> Bool in
            print("Inside search filter")

                if location.country.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
            {
                flag = true
                matchedArray.append(location.country)
            }
                else if location.state.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
           {
                flag = true
                matchedArray.append(location.state + unichar + location.country )
            }
            else if location.district.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
            {
                flag = true
                matchedArray.append(location.district + unichar + location.state + unichar + location.country )
             }
            else if location.subdistrict.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
             {
                flag = true
                matchedArray.append(location.subdistrict + unichar + location.district + unichar + location.state + unichar + location.country )
            }
            return flag
                }
            matchedArray = Array(Set(matchedArray)) //Remove duplicates and assign
            dropButton.dataSource = matchedArray
            dropButton.show()
            self.searchGeoLocationBut.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't get your question first you disable the button and at the end of condition you set it enable. What you really need?

Comment: what is the use of `return flag`

Comment: may be your if case is executed every-time an reenables it again

Comment: As @InderKumarRathore says, you need to move your disable logic to the end or before each return statement.

Comment: @Abhishek --> Though i have " self.searchGeoLocationBut.isEnabled = false" at the  top and before the "filter" step of array struct variable, the button is not getting disabled. The button gets disabled after execution of " _ = locdata.filter { (location: Location) -> Bool in" this line. The filter step takes time about 3-5 secs where i need to disable the button to prevent the user to tap it again. I wanted the button to be disabled first and execute the "filter" statement.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, Thats needed to  return a BOOL value to Filter statement. Thats not an issue here..Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore : It was at the bottom only when i initially coded. I moved the button disable and enable steps many places but nothing worked.